# Why I feel cool in a region with lot of trees inspite of humidity by transporation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, humidity

Today I went for a walk and entered a region with lot of trees, It feel a sudden chill, a cool feeling (comparatively)

Why, Although trees perform transpiration that cause moisture so we should feel warm but I feel cool?

Comment: And to transpire, they liquid in the leaves turns into vapor in the air. That takes energy. Think of it as the trees sweating.

Comment: One more doubt  , why in cold + humid weather , I still feel cool although I cannt sweat (I mean no further humidity in that area) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trees draw liquid water from the ground and transport it to the leaves. This water then evaporates through the process of transpiration. Turning liquid water into water vapor requires a significant amount of energy due to water's high latent heat of vaporization. The process of transpiration absorbs heat energy from the surrounding area, resulting in a cooling effect - this is known as transpiration cooling. It's a form of evaporative cooling, much like how a swamp cooler or human sweat has a cooling effect.

Comment: But when I pass through a forest near a pond in village, I feel a sudden warm burst on my chest?? If trees are there there should be cool n?

Comment: And why in cold + humid weather , I still feel cool although I cannt sweat (I mean no further humidity in that area) ??

Comment: @SureshChandraPal Transpiration produces humidity, which will inhibit your own sweat-based evaporative cooling. Even though the air around trees will tend to be cooler, it's possible you feel hotter because of the increased humidity.

Comment: So these are contrasting, one way i will feel cool as tree absorb surrounding heat, other I will ALSO feel hot as increase humidity!! How can both possible at a time?